# Seed for sample accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have followed Hartl's tutorial to make a ToDoList with a tagging system, also with the help of this [word guide](https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBa2qs9CFZQ). However I don't understand what are the actual arguments being used to initialise tags in a `User` instance. What would be the correct way of creating sample `User` accounts based on this code that I have made and how would you generally figure out how these methods are actually called?

Here is my code after implementing the things taught in the tutorial, please do inform me if more information is required.

Micropost controller

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
    params[:tag] ? @microposts = Micropost.tagged_with(params[:tag]) : @microposts = Micropost.all
  end


  def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params))
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "You have deleted a task!"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :tag_list, :tag, 
        {tag_ids: [] }, :tag_ids)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

Micropost model

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings, :dependent => :delete_all
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140 }
  attr_accessor :tag_list



  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by!(name: name).microposts
  end

  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select('tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count')
    .joins(:taggings).group('taggings.tag_id')
  end

  def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(', ')
  end

  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(',').map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

I have personally tried this but my rake got aborted because I don't understand how the code works.

```
10.times do
    content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
    users.each do |user|
      tag_list = Faker::Lorem.words(3)
      user.microposts.create(content: content, tag_list: tag_list)
    end
end
```

Error message from terminal after `rails db:migrate:reset` then `rails db:seed`

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for ["aut", "rerum", "magni"]:Array
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/app/models/micropost.rb:27:in `block in tag_list='
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/app/models/micropost.rb:26:in `map'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/app/models/micropost.rb:26:in `tag_list='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `public_send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `_assign_attribute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `_assign_attributes'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `_assign_attributes'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:337:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:154:in `build_association'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:281:in `build_record'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:358:in `block in _create_record'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:129:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:194:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:128:in `transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:357:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:121:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:196:in `create'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:347:in `create'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/db/seeds.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/db/seeds.rb:25:in `each'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/db/seeds.rb:25:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/db/seeds.rb:23:in `times'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/db/seeds.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:270:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:184:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/isaac/Documents/CVWO/cvwo_assignment/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Could you show log with error?

Comment: Could you tell what is the real blocker for you? You can show your logs with error?

Comment: Hi, do both of you mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function:

```
  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(',').map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
```

expects a string, like "foo,bar,baz".

However, this test code:

```
  tag_list = Faker::Lorem.words(3)
  user.microposts.create(content: content, tag_list: tag_list)
```

Is passing an array, like ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

You can turn the array into a string using #join, like this:

```
  tag_list = Faker::Lorem.words(3).join(",")
  user.microposts.create(content: content, tag_list: tag_list)
```